# Find groups where value is not the same for all rows in each group

Tags: pandas

I need to identify ids where all the amounts for that id are not equal.

Id 1 have values 10, 10, 20 so that is one, id 2 have values 5 and 5 so I dont want to find that id.

This seems complicated:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[1,1,1,2,2,3,3], "amount":[10,10,20,5,5,20,10]})
  # id    amount
  #  1      10
  #  1      10
  #  1      20
  #  2       5
  #  2       5
  #  3      20
  #  3      10
   
temp = pd.merge(left=df, right=df.groupby("id")["amount"].unique().rename("amounts"), left_on="id", right_index=True)
  # id  amount   amounts
  #  1      10  [10, 20]
  #  1      10  [10, 20]
  #  1      20  [10, 20]
  #  2       5       [5]
  #  2       5       [5]
  # ...
differ = temp.loc[temp.apply(lambda x: len(x["amounts"]), axis=1)>1]["id"].unique()
#array([1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for `Series` and then filter index values greate like `1`:

```
s = df.groupby("id")["amount"].nunique()

arr = s.index[s.gt(1)]
print (arr)
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64', name='id')
```